# Getting a uicollectionview to start on the second cell

Tags: uicollectionview, nsindexpath, collectionview

I have have a line based collection view, each cell takes up the whole screen. How do I get the collectionview to start on the second cell ? I am a noob to both collectionviews and iOS.

[ 0 ] | [ 1 ] | [ 2 ] | [ 3 ]

So you can only see one cell at a time, I want it to start on indexpath.row 1 as soon as the user gets to the collectionview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with the

```
scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:
```

method but I can see where @Lê Quý Sang method could work

Thanks!